# How do I delete an html tag or reassign an indicator to another tag? | Webflow - exported site |

Tags: javascript, html, webflow

For me it was depressing news from support that we can’t remove the html tag from the pages.

The thing is, I only want to use the section, not the whole page.

And, accordingly, the page can not have two,three or more HTML tags.
If I remove it, the animation will stop playing as this tag has a JavaScript indicator.

Did anyone have the same goal as me? using a section instead of a page?

Is there a way to remove this tag/reassign the indicator to another tag (div, for example)? Please help me find a solution to what I think is a global problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How can you have content outside of the ``<html>`` tag? I think you are a bit confused

Comment: @Alexander hello

You're right, but you're a little confused. 

I have page. And I created the necessary section in webflow and now I want to put it inside the created page. 

That is, in this case, the html tag in the exported webflow site is not needed, because I use only the section. Only a specific block with content.

Comment: Alright, I think that's clearer. So, your question is rather "How to use page fragments in webflow?"

Comment: Yes, certain elements and content blocks, but outside of webflow - exported site. 

That is, without the html tag, but with javascript animation

At the moment, these lines are data-webflow and without which javascript refuses to play on the page. 

That is, I need a solution that will allow me to reassign this data-webflow to another tag.

Comment: If you have different sections and display or work with one .Simple in javascript dynamicaly hide all but display one that you need

Comment: Hello, @LDS I don't quite understand you. I use webflow-because I'm far from Javascript. 

Can you elaborate on what you mean? In your free time

I use the whole wf.javascript file.